# How can I downcast an object using only late-binding in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, osisoft

I am writing a VBA application, and for a specific function, I am using only late-binding, as most of the users of the application won't have the reference installed (and won't use this specific function).

The object I am using behaves like:

```
class PISDK{
    PIServer GetServer(string hostName)
}
```

The `GetServer` method returns a `PIServer` object, but a more specific interface exists, implementing `PIServer`:

```
interface IGetPoints2 : PIServer{}
```

I would like to downcast the `PIServer` object to a `IGetPoints2` object.

Without doing anything, I get a PIServer object:

```
Dim PiSdk As Object
Dim PiServer As Object

Set PiSdk = CreateObject("PISDK.PISDK")
Set PiServer = PiSdk.GetServer("foo")
```

Looking at `PiServer` in the debugger confirms that.

Using a strongly typed variable should work, but I do not want to reference any of the types used here.

How can I downcast this object using late-binding only?

Comment: You can manually call `QueryInterface` using `olelib.tlb` (Edanmo's OLE interfaces & functions) type library (you don't need to redistribute it), but are you sure it does not work if you simply try to call the method?

Answer (score 0):

[Please read this:](https://pisquare.osisoft.com/thread/7755)

- As you are not adding a reference to the PI SDK Type Library, I
  believe you cannot use "rtInterpolated" as the second parameter of
  the ArcValue method; instead, you can use the corresponding number
  (which is 3 for "rtInterpolated" in the RetrievalTypeConstants
  enumeration).
- VBA with late binding is tricky with    optional
  parameters, as we cannot omit them when calling a method.    Instead,
  you need to use either Nothing (in case the optional    parameter is
  an object) or "" (in case the optional parameter is a    string) as
  "parameter placeholders" (by the way, the same happens in
  VBScript, a scripting language for scripts contained in files with
  .vbs extension that run independently from any application).
- able to put some functional sample code together, which is more
  complete and will hopefully help you.

Comment: "*VBA with late binding is tricky with optional parameters, as we cannot omit them when calling a method*" - not true.